# How to bind a select list with SproutCore 2.0 and Handlebars

Tags: sproutcore, handlebars.js

Given the following SC.View object:

```
var view = SC.View.create({
  templateName: 'people',
  people: [],
  selectedPersonId: null});
```

and the following people Handlebars template:

```
<select>
  {{#each people}}
  <option {{bindAttr id="id"}}>{{name}}</option>
  {{/each}}
</select>
```

What would be the best way to bind the selectedPersonId to the select list?

(@stackoverflow: Reputation of 1500+ to create new tags? really?.... #sproutcore20 #handlebars)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to create a custom view for this. I use one implemented in CoffeeScript which looks basically like that

```
MyApp.SelectionView = SC.CollectionView.extend
    tagName: 'select'
    value: null

    willInsertElement: ->
        @_elementValueDidChange()

    change: ->
        @_elementValueDidChange()

    _elementValueDidChange: ->
        views = SC.View.views
        selectedOptions = @$('option:selected')
        ### Multiple selections
        @set('value', selectedOptions.toArray().map( (el) ->
            SC.get(views[el.id], 'content')
        ))
        ###
        @set('value', SC.get(views[selectedOptions.prop('id')], 'content'))
```

As you can easily spot, this is for a single selection. Use the commented out code to upgrade this to a multi selection.

There is also a pull request for a select view (meanwhile this was closed by its author because it does not use the new metaphore code), see https://github.com/sproutcore/sproutcore20/pull/65. If you are still on beta3 this patch should provide the selection functionality for you.

Comment: So from the pull request I guess it looks like you'd also need an SC.SelectOption to render the <option>s?

Comment: That might be the case in beta3. In master this is no longer necessary since "select" is now one of the tags which is known to the collection handler. This was not the case before, but I'm not quite sure if this was introduced before or after beta3.

Comment: Just checked. The pull request is based on the orginal beta version of SC2. There where couple of changes to the collection view in beta2. Since I'm not using the proposed patch, I can't verify that it is still working.